# I want to replace a word that appears 2 times in a file... with a new word that a user types in

Tags: python

**The task is:**

Create a Mad Libs program that reads in text files and lets the user add their own text anywhere the word ADJECTIVE, NOUN, ADVERB, or VERB appears in the text file. For example, the text file madlibs1.txt has the following content:

*The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was
unaffected by these*

The program would find these occurrences and prompt the user to replace them, like so:

Enter an adjective:
silly
Enter a noun:
chandelier
Enter a verb:
screamed
Enter a noun:
pickup truck

**The following text should then be printed:**
The silly panda walked to the chandelier and then screamed. A nearby pickup
truck was unaffected by these events.

**My code looks like this**

```
with open('madlibs1.txt') as f:

file = f.read()
file = file.replace('ADJECTIVE', input('Enter an adjective: '))
file = file.replace('NOUN', input('Enter a noun: '))
file = file.replace('VERB', input('Enter a verb: '))
file = file.replace('NOUN', input('Enter a noun: '))    

print(file)
```

But it prints chandelier twice because the key for NOUN is set to the first input from the user.

What can I do? Should I use split() or create an empty dictionary? Any ideas?

Regards
Sedar

Comment: So you need a way to replace only the first occurrence of NOUN? Try reading the documentation for `replace()` and perhaps you’ll see a way to do it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace

Comment: According to the documentation you can specify how many replacements to make.

Comment: Can't you use another variable name for second Noun like `NOUN1`? You can then replace this correctly using your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a template. You might be able to use jinja or you can use regular python. There are a lot of options for templates.

```
# my_template.txt
The {adjective1} {adjective2} fox {verb1} over the {adjective3} dog
```

Then just use format on the string

```
with open("my_template.txt", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    
replace = {}
replace['adjective1'] = input('Enter an adjective: ')
replace['adjective2'] = input('Enter an adjective: ')
replace['verb1'] = input('Enter an verb: ')
replace['adjective3'] = input('Enter an adjective: ')

txt = contents.format(**replace)
print(txt)
```

You can also automate this

```
from string import digits


remove_digits = str.maketrans('', '', digits)


def find_variables(contents):
    """Iterator that yields (variable name, variable type) found 
    in the given contents.
    """
    while True:
        idx = contents.find('{')
        if idx == -1:
            break

        idx2 = contents[idx:].find('}')
        if idx2 == -1:
            break

        varname = contents[idx+1:idx2]
        var_type = varname.translate(remove_digits)  # Not Tested
        contents = contents[idx2:]

        yield varname, var_type


with open("my_template.txt", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()

replace = {varname: input('Enter one {}:'.format(var_type))
           for varname, var_type in find_variables(contents)}
    
txt = contents.format(**replace)
print(txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot change the file, you can use this one.

```py
with open('madlibs1.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip("\n")
        newline = ""

        for word in line.split(" "):
            
        
            if word.startswith(('ADJECTIVE', 'NOUN', 'VERB')):
                if word.endswith((',','.')): word, punctuation = word[:-1], word[-1]
                
                word = input(f'Enter a {word}')

                if punctuation:
                    word += punctuation
                    punctuation = ""

            newline = " ".join([newline, word]) if newline else word
        print(newline)

# 'The red panda walked to the dog and then sit. A nearby cat was unaffected by these events.'
```